# Receiving error when merging two linked lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to merge two linked lists in Python, but every time I receive the error: type object 'List' has no attribute 'merge' when it clearly has the function for merging.

---

**Sample Input:**
8 11 20 24 50
5 9 10 30 33 40 45
**Sample Output:**
5 8 9 10 11 20 24 30 33 40 45 50

---

```
class Node: 
    def __init__ (self, data): 
       self.data = data 
       self.next = None
class List: 
    def __init__(self): 
       self.head = None
    def append(self, new_data): 
       new_node = Node(new_data) 
       if self.head is None: 
            self.head = new_node 
            return
       last = self.head 
       while last.next: 
            last = last.next
       last.next = new_node 
    def merge(head1, head2): 
       temp = None
       if head1 is None: 
          return head2 
       if head2 is None: 
          return head1 
       if head1.data <= head2.data: 
          temp = head1 
          temp.next = merge(head1.next, head2) 
       else: 
          temp = head2
          temp.next = merge(head1, head2.next)
       return temp
```

For taking input:

```
inp = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
inp2 = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
l = List()
l2 = List()
for i in inp:
    l.append(i)
for i in inp2:
    l2.append(i)
rez = List.merge(l, l2)
print(rez)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Maybe you left off the `@static_method` decorator? `merge` is currently an instance method, not a class method (although you left `self` off as the first argument)

Comment: Are the parameters to `merge()` supposed to be `List`s, or `Node`s?  You're not being consistent about what you call it with.

Comment: I don't see how this code could produce that error.  In your real code, is the `merge()` function indented underneath  the `List` class?

Comment: When I run your code I get a different error btw `AttributeError: 'List' object has no attribute 'data'` which is correct as `.data` is on your `Node` class but `if head1.data <= head2.data:` you are mixing up Nodes and Lists. I recommend you start using type hints to make your code clearer. If you do, you'll see that `List` is a bad choice of name as it's already taken by the `typing` module

Comment: @jasonharper They are supposed to be lists.

Comment: @JohnGordon The merge function is indeed indented inside the List class.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @Dan The List class acts like a wrapper for the Node class, so by that I believe it should have access to Node's attributes. Thanks for the name suggestion :)

Comment: @Milovan no it should not. You'll need `list1.head.data` to access the Node's members. You are mixing up what are lists and nodes. Take a look at the edit to my answer to see how to make sure your merge function only ever gets lists instead of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting yourself muddled with the heads and the list object types. You're calling it with lists sometimes and recursively calling it with heads, fixed it up for ya:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__ (self, data): 
       self.data = data 
       self.next = None
class List: 
    def __init__(self): 
       self.head = None
    def append(self, new_data): 
       new_node = Node(new_data) 
       if self.head is None: 
            self.head = new_node 
            return
       last = self.head 
       while last.next: 
            last = last.next
       last.next = new_node 
    def merge(head1, head2):
       list_given = type(head1) == List
       if list_given:
           head1 = head1.head
           head2 = head2.head
       temp = None
       if head1 is None: 
          return head2 
       if head2 is None: 
          return head1 
       if head1.data <= head2.data: 
          temp = head1 
          temp.next = List.merge(head1.next, head2) 
       else: 
          temp = head2
          temp.next = List.merge(head1, head2.next)

       if list_given:
           new_list = List()
           new_list.head = temp
           return new_list
       else:
           return temp 


inp = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
inp2 = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]

l = List()
l2 = List()
for i in inp:
    l.append(i)
for i in inp2:
    l2.append(i)
rez = List.merge(l, l2)
print(rez)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your method to be callable on the class rather than on an object, you should make it [static](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/#static-methods):

```
@staticmethod
def merge(head1, head2): 
    # etc...
```

You could also make your code a lot clearer (including to yourself) by using type hints as you are mixing up what is a `List` and what is a `Node`:

```
from typing import Any, Optional

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data: Any):
        self.data = data
        self.next: Optional[Node] = None  # might be Optional["Node"] since it inside it's own definition, I'm not sure check the mypy docs


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head: Optional[Node] = None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_data: Any) -> None:
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        last = self.head
        while last.next:
            last = last.next
        last.next = new_node

    @staticmethod
    def merge(list1: "LinkedList", list2: "LinkedList") -> "LinkedList":
        if list1.head is None:
            return list2
        if list2.head is None:
            return list1
        if list1.head.data <= list2.head.data:
            head = list1.head
            list1 = LinkedList(list1.head.next)
        else:
            head = list2.head
            list2 = LinkedList(list2.head.next)
        temp = LinkedList(head)
        temp.head.next = LinkedList.merge(list1, list2).head
        return temp
```

test it with:

```
inp = [8, 11, 20, 24, 50]
inp2 = [5, 9, 10, 30, 33, 40, 45]
l = LinkedList()
l2 = LinkedList()
for i in inp:
    l.append(i)
for i in inp2:
    l2.append(i)
rez = LinkedList.merge(l, l2)

temp = rez.head
print(temp.data)
while temp.next:
    temp = temp.next
    print(temp.data)
```

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but the problems run deeper than this. Running the code with your solution will give an error: AttributeError: 'List' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Agreed - but that wasn't the question

Comment: Thank you for your time! Will take in consideration :)